# Filtering data frame in R : Combining GREP with variable names?

Tags: r

I am looking to filter a data frame based on two criteria: 1. few key variables and, 2. Several other variables with a specific pattern.

Usually I use the following code:

```
mydata <- rawData[,c("scenario","period","farmID",grep("planting_*",names(rawData), value = TRUE))]
```

The problem is happening after I updated R to the new version (3.5.3). Before it worked fine and I got what I wanted: a new data frame filtered by variables.

However, now R is returning a vector only with the variable names (with no observation).

Could anyone help me with this issue?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This code never worked: You can’t mix names and numeric indices in the same subsetting vector.

Furthermore, your regular expression is wrong: `*` should be `.*` — otherwise you’d be searching for the word `planting` followed by zero or more underscores. In your case this won’t make a difference but it’s a different expression and thus misleading to readers of your code.

However, you *can* make it work by making `grep` return the matched names instead of indices:

```r
planting_names <- grep("planting_.*", names(rawData), value = TRUE)
mydata <- rawData[ , c("scenario", "period", "farmID", planting_names)]
```

Comment: Hi Konrad, many thanks for your reply. Yes, it does work on previous R version, I have it here in my screen with R 3.3.1 and it does what I expected. But in the other computer with the new version it does not...

Thanks for your suggestion, I tried it here and it also does not work, it returns the same vector as the command I posted.

Comment: @MarceloCarauta I’m confident that the code does *not* work. It may produce output on your old installation, but that output is wrong. Check it carefully and you’ll realise that your `grep` expression either returns nothing, or that your data.frame happens to contain columns that have numbers as names. *Those* columns would have been removed, not the columns you wanted to select via your regular expression.